# What does it mean: “may she not somehow...”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> May she not somehow have come into someone’s dream because the feet of that delicate-bodied idol ache today!

It’s not an idol made out of stone. It just figuratively
conveys that that idol is a woman whom the  author is in love with. That is an urdu couplet that I’ve attempted to literally translate into English. Does “**may she not have come into**...” imply that the poet is uncertain or suspects she has come into someone’s dream therefore her feet hurt?

Comment: I've no idea what the text after "because" means - but it's poetry, so that's not unusual. Initial ***may she not** [have done something]* is a highly stylised way of asking ***Is it possible** [that she has done something]*. You wouldn't be likely to use that construction in "normal" contexts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to analyse the syntax /meaning of (badly?) translated poetry

Answer (score 0):

The phrase:

> May she not somehow have come into someone’s dream

I would take to mean:

> Is it possible that she somehow appeared in someone's dream?

I have no idea if this is a good translation or not. I do not speak Urdu, and wouldn't know even if I had the original.

I don't see any connection between coming into someone's dram and feet hurting. It is not at all clear to me what connection the poet might intend to imply.